# How to catch SQL errors with AsyncPG?

Tags: python, asyncpg

I'm having a real hard time finding any examples of how to error handle in AsyncPG.
I am executing this query:

```
await pg_con.execute("UPDATE users set x = $1, y = $2 WHERE z = $3", x, y, z)
```

I want to be able to catch any SQL errors, such as if the record does not exist. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asyncpg has module exceptions with all possible exceptions. You can catch specific error, e.g.:

```py
import asyncpg
try:
    await pg_con.execute("UPDATE users set x = $1, y = $2 WHERE z = $3", x, y, z)
except asyncpg.ForeignKeyViolationError as e:
    print('error occurred', e)
```

or just catch `asyncpg.PostgresError` or even `Exception` instead.
Also, it's sometimes easy to check exception detail in python interpreter:

```py
try:
    await pg_con.execute(query)
except Exception as e:
    breakpoint()  # then use e.__class__, e.args, dir(e), etc
```